# Google +1 button errors every time i click it

Tags: facebook-opengraph, google-plus, google-plus-one

we have implemented the google +1 button on [our product pages](http://www.topshop.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?beginIndex=1&viewAllFlag=&catalogId=33057&storeId=12556&productId=8460926&langId=-1&sort_field=Relevance&categoryId=928188&parent_categoryId=203984&pageSize=20) and every time i click it it fails.

It has been happening since i changed the Open graph meta tags in the page to point to a larger image. The reason i did this is because Google seem to have some weird rule that says that your product image taken from the url in the open graph tags has to be over certain dimensions or it won't appear in the +1 box, hence the reason i changed the meta tag to point to this larger version:

```
 <meta property="og:image" content="http://media.topshop.com/wcsstore/TopShop/images/catalog/16F02DBLK_normal.jpg"/>
```

Any ideas why this would of caused an issue so that the +1 button is now not working at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [can I force google plus button to use open graph url?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861651/can-i-force-google-plus-button-to-use-open-graph-url)

Comment: Well, yes it kind of is a duplicate in that i want to use Open graph data, but i already know that it is possible to do this. My question is more fundamental - why did changing the og:image tag to point to a slighty bigger image break the google+1 button completely?

Comment: Check the rich snippet testing tool http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

Comment: Hi there, yeah i have already tried testing the page URL in the rich snippet testing tool, but to no avail. I just get the following error message: **"We are sorry. The service you requested is currently unavailable. Please try again later".** Is this tool always down - or is it something on the page i'm trying to test that is causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

For your image, you should be using schema.org microdata instead of Open Graph. You can generate this from the Google+ developer page here:

https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/

The image itself is not likely to be the cause of the +1 button not rendering or responding correctly.

For the +1 button, there are a number of things that can cause the button to error. Here are a few things to check:

- Is the page completely visible to Google (public). If the Google proxies that calculate the way the share renders are not able to access the site, you will get an error.
- Is the markup around the button causing errors to occur? You can try commenting out sections of the page until it renders to isolate what parts of your page could be causing errors while parsing the button script.

To test both of these at the same time, use the [Google webmasters tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) for testing your rich snippets to see what Google sees. If the Google webmasters tool is giving you errors... odds are that Google can't see your site or at least can't see the referenced page. This could be [a bigger problem with your web server](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/).

You might also want to try giving Google a hint for the +1 button to where it needs to be targeting and moving to the HTML5 compatible syntax:

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-annotation="inline" 
    data-width="300" data-href="https://yoursite.com">
</div>
```

You could further test whether the +1 button is working with another button that targets a known working page as follows:

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-annotation="inline"
    data-width="300" data-href="https://developers.google.com/+">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi there, i am using a really simple implementation of the button:



`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>

<g:plusone annotation="none"></g:plusone>`

and i still get this error. Also it says in Google documentation that the +1 button prefers schema.org microdata but will use Open Graph if this is not present so i don't see what the problem is with that.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because google plus is not able to find the image.In my case there was a space in the image url in og meta tags. I replaced the space with '%20' and everything worked.